# nvd3 (d3.js) date format returns incorrect month

Tags: date, d3.js, nvd3.js

My data looks like this:

```
[{ x="2013-06-01", y=3}, { x="2013-07-01", y=7 }, { x="2013-08-01", y=3 }]
```

Chart x-axis is formatted as so:

```
chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel('Date')
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b %Y')(new Date(d)); })
    ;
```

`%b` returns May, Jun, July respectively for the dates 2013-06-01, 2013-07-01, 2013-08-01

Why is it returning the previous month, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: If the date is formatted as 2013-06-02, it will return the correct month... does someone know what is happening to cause this?

Comment: It's possible the problem has to do with timezones -- if the parsing algorithm is assuming one timezone and the format algorithm is using a different one, it could be the difference between May 31 and June 1.  To have greater control, you can specify an x-accessor function on your chart that uses a d3 time format parsing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amelia is correct it's because of timezone difference and because Date defaults to `24:00:00` if you don't specify a time. So, in case of EDT, which is -4:00, you lose 4 hours which puts you in the previous day `(May 31 2013 20:00:00)` and because the days in your dates are `01`, this puts you in the previous month.

To bypass this you could append a time to your date if that is allowable in your case.

```
chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel('Date')
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        d = d.split('-')
        // Create new date by using new Date(year, month, day, hour, second, ms)
        // Subtracting 1 is necessary since Javascript months are 0 - 11.
        return d3.time.format('%b %Y')(new Date(d[0], +d[1] - 1, d[2], 12, 0, 0));
    });
```

Here is a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLECR/54/)